# retrieve full documents by distinct value using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have customer documents constructed like so:

```
{
   "name" : "blah"
   "phone": "blah"
   "customerId" : 123
}, 
{
   "name" : "blah"
   "phone": "blah"
   "customerId" : 123
},
{
   "name" : "blah"
   "phone": "blah"
   "customerId" : 256
}
```

I want to retrive full documents of those with the name having the "b" letter:

```
Customer.find({"name": { '$regex' : req.query.name}})
```

Does the trick, but i want only one for each customerId, meaning from the 3 objects i wrote i want 2 coming back, the one with customerId 256 and the other one with the customer id of 123.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation framework for this:

```
Customer.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "name": { '$regex' : req.query.name } } }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$customerId", 
            "name": { "$last": "$$ROOT" } } } 
    ], callback(err, result)
)
```